# How do I create a line with fixed size from a single point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gdal, vector, geometry-conversion, qgis-3

My question pretty much sums up my problem. Basically, I have a layer containing points:

[image]

And I need to convert them into lines with fixed size (25 meters). I don't care if the point will be taken as starting point or middle point of this line, and I don't care about the direction of each line. By the end I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Do you guys know how should I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, please take the [tour] to have a clear understanding on asking questions and to get quick answers.

Comment: A line geometry, or a symbol around a point?

Comment: I need a line geometry. I've tried buffering and it would work if I needed polygons, but as I said, I need a line with 25 meters.

Answer (score 4):

As you have tagged `QGIS3.2`, you could try **Geometry by Expression** tool (in the *Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry*).

One simplistic example would be a 25m-line extending to NE from each point:

```
 make_line($geometry, translate($geometry, 25* cos(radians(45)), 25* sin(radians(45))))
```

You can easily understand the endpoint of the line is defined by `translate($geometry, x, y)`

[image]

FWIW, we can change the azimuth (currently 45 degrees) to other values or attribute field if needed.